# Setting up a strategy delivering a smooth heat transfer solution

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, heat-equation

I have a polymeric film that undergoes a two-step cooling process. First, it spends `time1` in air. Then it comes in contact with a piece of steel at a temperature `Tr1` but only on one side. I tried to solve the heat conduction problem to calculate the temperature of the film as function of time through its thickness, as follows:

All parameters:

```
(*k is in W/mK; rho in Kg/m3; Cp in J/(kgK)*)
kf = 0.33; rhof = 940; Cpf = 2100;          
h = 20000;  (*W/m2K*)

thickness = 0.03;   (*expressed in millimeters*)  

Tair = 20;
T0 = 260;    (* initial temperature*)
Tr1 = 100;   (*cold temperature *)

(*meters*)
Length1 = 0.02;   
Length2 = 2;  

speed= 2.5; (*m/s*)

time1 = Length1/speed;
time2 = Length2/speed;
```

Step1 cooling: film in air

```
eqn = rhof*Cpf*D[T[t, x], t] - kf*Laplacian[T[t, x], {x}];

ic = T[0, x] == T0;
bc1 = NeumannValue[(10^-3)*h*(Tair - T[t, x]), x == -thickness/2];
bc2 = NeumannValue[(10^-3)*h*(Tair - T[t, x]), x == thickness/2];
Tfun1 = NDSolveValue[{eqn == bc1 + bc2, ic}, 
  T, {t, 0, time1}, {x, -thickness/2, thickness/2}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}]

Plot3D[Tfun1[t, x], {t, 0, time1}, {x, -thickness/2, thickness/2}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Step2 cooling: film touching a piece of steel:

```
eqn = rhof*Cpf*D[T[t, x], t] - kf*Laplacian[T[t, x], {x}];

ic = T[0, x] == Tfun1[time1, x];
bc1 = NeumannValue[(10^-3)*h*(Tair - T[t, x]), x == -thickness/2];
bc2 = DirichletCondition[T[t, x] == Tr1, x == thickness/2];
Tfun2 = NDSolveValue[{eqn == bc1, bc2, ic}, 
  T, {t, 0, time2}, {x, -thickness/2, thickness/2}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}]

Plot3D[Tfun2[t, x], {t, 0, time2}, {x, -thickness/2, thickness/2}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

As visible from plotting the solution shows oscillations. I am looking for tips to set up a strategy to arrive to a smooth solution.

thanks

Comment: These oscillations depend on mesh. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is numerical oscillation coming from rough mesh used. To make `T` more smooth we can use mesh generated as follows

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
thickness = 0.03;   (*expressed in millimeters*)mesh = ToElementMesh[FullRegion[1], {{-thickness/2, thickness/2}}, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-6]

(*Out[]= ElementMesh[{{-0.015, 0.015}}, {LineElement["<" 30000 ">"]}]*)
```

Solution

```
(*k is in W/mK;rho in Kg/m3;Cp in J/(kgK)*)kf = 0.33; rhof = 940; Cpf \
= 2100;
h = 20000;  (*W/m2K*)
Tair = 20;
T0 = 260;    (*initial temperature*)
Tr1 = 100;   (*cold temperature*)

(*meters*)
Length1 = 0.02;
Length2 = 2;

speed = 2.5; (*m/s*)

time1 = Length1/speed;
time2 = Length2/speed;
(*Step1 cooling:film in air*)

eqn = rhof*Cpf*D[T[t, x], t] - kf*Laplacian[T[t, x], {x}];

ic = T[0, x] == T0;
bc1 = NeumannValue[(10^-3)*h*(Tair - T[t, x]), x == -thickness/2];
bc2 = NeumannValue[(10^-3)*h*(Tair - T[t, x]), x == thickness/2];
Tfun1 = NDSolveValue[{eqn == bc1 + bc2, ic}, T, {t, 0, time1}, 
  Element[{x}, mesh]]
```

We can compare old solution (blue solid line) and new solution (red dashed line) at `t=time1` in one plot
[image: Figure 1]

Second part of solution looks much better

```
(*Step2 cooling:film touching a piece of steel:*)
eqn = rhof*Cpf*D[T[t, x], t] - kf*Laplacian[T[t, x], {x}];

ic = T[0, x] == Tfun1[time1, x];
bc1 = NeumannValue[(10^-3)*h*(Tair - T[t, x]), x == -thickness/2];
bc2 = DirichletCondition[T[t, x] == Tr1, x == thickness/2];
Tfun2 = NDSolveValue[{eqn == bc1, bc2, ic}, T, {t, 0, time2}, 
   Element[{x}, mesh]];


Plot3D[Tfun2[t, x], {t, 0, time2}, {x, -thickness/2, thickness/2}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "ArmyColors", 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Figure 2]